# Route [name] not defined in laravel 4.1

Tags: php, variables, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a problem within my routes and variable. i need to pass the variable in an foreach loop to the routes. here is the error meesage "Route [patientName] not defined".
here is the homepage.blade.php:

```
@foreach($patientsList as $patients)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $patients->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $patients->email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $patients->address }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $patients->phone_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $patients->type }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{ URL::route('patientName', array('pname' => $patients->name)) }}" class="view-profile">View Profile</a></td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

routes.php:

```
Route::get('patientName/{pname}','PatientsController@getPatientName');
```

controller

```
<?php
class PatientsController extends BaseController{
    /*some functions*/
    function getPatientName($patientName){
        return $patientName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** 

`URL::route` generates a link to a named route - so it expects a route's name as a parameter. In your code, you do not specify your route's name, so the URL helper cannot generate the link and throws an route not found error. Check the corrections below

```
//routes.php - specify a route's name 
Route::get('patientName/{pname}', array('as'=>'patientName', 'uses'=>'PatientsController@getPatientName'));
```

Now you can safely use

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('patientName', array('pname' => $patients->name)) }}" class="view-profile">View Profile</a>
```

IMPORTANT: remember to run `composer dump-autoload` after you modify the routes.php file.

**Solution 2** 

On the other hand, you can just change the method for url generation and use `URL::to`. It expects a parameter containing path.

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('patientName/'.$patients->name) }}" class="view-profile">View Profile</a>
```

**Conclusion**
Refer to the documentation for details on different ways of safe url generation based on routes
http://laravel.com/docs/routing

Also be sure to check the URL helper docs for some useful stuff
http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls